# Расположение блоков, bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Доброй ночи! Учусь верстать по PSD макетам

У меня есть блоки (см. скриншот), каким образом разместить их четко по центру?

Пробовал играться с "col-sm-offset-2", к сожалению дробных он не понимает :)

Размер блоков должен сохраниться. Заранее благодарен за любую помощь :)

HTML5:

```
    <div class="left">

   <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-2">

    <div class="rightcontainer">

    </div>

    <div class="rightcontainer2">

    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="middle">

   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 col-lg-5">

    <div class="middlecontainer">

    </div>

    <div class="middlecontainer">

    </div>

    <div class="middlecontainer">

    </div>

   </div>

   </div>

  <div class="right">

   <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-lg-2">

    <div class="leftcontainer">

    </div>

    <div class="leftcontainer2">

    </div>

   </div>

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
/*Левая секция*/

.leftcontainer {
  width: 278px;
  height: 302px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0.2px #a3a3a3;
  margin-bottom: 4.5%;
}

.leftcontainer2:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #a3a3a3;
  border-radius: 10px;  
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.leftcontainer2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 278px;
  height: 405px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0.2px #a3a3a3;
}

.leftcontainer:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #a3a3a3;
  border-radius: 10px;  
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/*Левая секция*/

/*Центральная секция*/

.middlecontainer {
  width: 755px;
  height: 230px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0.2px #a3a3a3;
  margin-bottom: 1.4%;
}

.middlecontainer:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 1px #a3a3a3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/*Центральная секция*/

/*Правая секция*/


.rightcontainer {
  width: 190px;
  height: 302px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0.2px #a3a3a3;
  margin-bottom: 4.5%;
}

.rightcontainer2:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #a3a3a3;
  border-radius: 10px;  
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.rightcontainer2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 190px;
  height: 405px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0.2px #a3a3a3;
}

.rightcontainer:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #a3a3a3;
  border-radius: 10px;  
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/*Правая секция*/
```

Медиа запросы:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.header{height: 300px;}
.logo{display:block; margin-top:35px; margin-left: 25%;}
div.button{margin:10px auto 20px;}
a.onbutton{margin:10px auto 20px;}
p.incounter{font-size: 1em;}
p.outcounter{font-size: 1em;}
p.outcounter2{font-size: 1em;}
a.downloadprog{font-size: 1em;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1800px) {
div.button{width: 200px; height: 45px; margin-top: 6%; margin-left: 20%;}
a.onbutton{font-size: 0.9em; margin-top: 6%; margin-left: 3%;}
p.incounter{font-size: 0.70em;}
p.outcounter{font-size: 0.70em;}
p.outcounter2{font-size: 0.70em;}
a.downloadprog{font-size: 1em;}
p.inheader{font-size: 1.025em;}
a.downloadprog{margin-left: 22.5%; font-size: 1.6em;}
.info{margin-top: 9.5%; margin-right: 10%; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
a.downloadprog{margin-left: 20.5%; font-size: 1.6em;}
.info{margin-top: 10%; margin-right: 8%; }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
.header{height: 300px;}
.header2{height: 170px;}
.logo{display:block; margin-top:35px; margin-left: 25%;}
a.logreg{top: 20%; left: 60%;}
div.button{width: 200px; height: 45px; margin-top: -7%; margin-left: 5%;}
.fa-sign-in{top: 20%; left: 59%;}
.orange{margin-top: -1.5%;}
p.inheader{margin-left: 10%;}
a.downloadprog{margin-left: 18.5%; font-size: 1em;}
p.incounter{left: 10%;}
p.outcounter{left: 10%;}
p.outcounter2{left: 10%;}
.info{margin-top: 45.3%; margin-left: 20%;}
}
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: col-sm-offset-1 не дал желаемого результата.

Comment: Тут offset вообще не надо использовать. Дизайн не адаптивный будет, насколько я понимаю?

Comment: @labris через медиа запросы сделал какой-никакой адаптив) Прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: Кроме блоков сейчас всё адекватно отображается на всех девайсах. В Bootstrap пока еще не вдавался

Comment: 1. Col-md-3. 2. Col-md-7 . 3. Col-md-2. А дальше если нужно, ширину делать по вложенному диву.

Comment: @labris, появилась новая проблема - страница съехала

Все блоки закинул в maincontent

.maincontent {
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
}

А при margin-left блоки стыкуются

http://imgur.com/a/N8LPg

Comment: Почему нельзя просто на Бутстрапе сделать?

Comment: @labris можно подробнее об этом?

Comment: http://bootstrap-3.ru/css.php#grid